# Deployed webapp on firebase but not authenticating when opened in linkedin

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have deployed a react web app on firebase, with google authentication and it works but when I try to open it inside Linkedin it says can't be authorized when used in this app.
Any solution?!
[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8jTX.jpg)!
[Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmboM.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain more what you did?

Comment: It says Google can not provide you safety inside the app  ,use the website in a browser.

Comment: And when I opened linkedin in browser and opened the webapp it worked.